# Limit job CPU usage SLURM

Tags: slurm

We are using SLURM to queue jobs on a shared computer, how do I go about limiting a job's thread utilisation by the number of threads requested? At the moment it's taken on honesty and users have been abusing this to jump the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to  specify a [TaskPlugin](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html#OPT_TaskPlugin) in your `slurm.conf`. By default, it has value `task/none`, which means no constraint.

If you set it to `task/affinity`, Slurm will use [CPUSETS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) to constrain the processes and threads to the CPUs that are allocated for the job.

If you set it to `task/cgroup`, Slurm will use [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) for that purpose. This option is much more flexible than the CPUSET option (it can put limits on virtually anything) but it requires more work to configure. See the [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/cgroups.html).

Comment: Is it also possible for SLURM to allow the job to use more threads once other jobs finish, or will the job continue to use its originally allocated number of threads?

Comment: No, the job will not be able to use more threads than it requested initially.